# My computer shuts down unexpectedly

Tags: memory, ssd, cpu, motherboard, windows-10

My PC's specifications are as follows (it's a custom build) :

> 1. Processor: **AMD FX8350 @ stock (4Ghz)**
> 2. GPU: **Gigabyte R7 260x 2GB 128bit Factory Overclocked @ 1625Mhz Memory and 1125Mhz Core**
> 3. Memory: **Kingston FuryX Black 4GB @ 1600Mhz x2**
> 4. Motherboard: **ASUS M5A97 EVO R2.0**
> 5. PSU: **450W (came with the chassis)**
> 6. SSD: **OCZ ARC100 120GB**
> 7. Operating System: **Windows 10 Pro**

When I play games sometimes my PC **shuts down** and the CPU and GPU are both around 50C, and sometimes it gets over 70C and they're fine.
I also get some **artifacts** even when not playing games, like when I'm internet browsing.

Comment: It's unlikely, but is it possible the PSU is overloaded with the overlooked card and everything else?

Comment: Maybe, but why the artifacts?

Comment: It could be because the graphics card is overclocked on an underpowered PSU

Comment: I'd start with a new power supply and go from there. If everything's good, then that's great. If you need further help, ask here

Comment: Alright, I have arranged some deal, and I'll get a 700W PSU, I don't know the manufacturer yet.

Comment: That should work

Comment: I hope so, otherwise I'll get a 750 TI GPU, by the way, in your opinion, which is better a 260x or a 750 TI ? Not Boost.

Comment: I don't know much about hardware. You could ask on reddit.

Comment: Before you go spending $ on PSU and/or GPU, try just reducing the video card's core and memory clock rates about 10% or so and see if the artifacts go away.

Comment: Already tried that, but I still get them, the weird thing is, I can underclock or overclock my GPU and not get them at all. This only happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it with another PSU, it's a weak point of PCs. Don't trust in noname PSUs that come with your case.

Comment: I have also thought of that, but the problem is, why do I get artifacts?

Comment: I don't really know but I've seen PSUs causing very strange problems.